# R get only 3 distinct Strings out of mutiple combinations

Tags: r

I extracted information out of a .csv file into a table and need to do a barplot out of one of the rows.

That row have 3 distinct strings but it can have more than 1 string in each row. Let's take this as example:

Row1 | Row2 | RowIWant | RowEtc ...

data | data | A        | data ...

```
          B
          C
          A, B
          A, B, C
```

assume A, B and C is text and not a char only. I want to make a barplot with A, B and C only and not with all the 6 possible combinations.

Right now the bar plot comes like this
[BarPlot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gnbBy.png)

I want it to have only the 3 distinct Strings instead of the 6 bars showing at the moment. Is this achievable? Sorry if it has already been answered but I couldn't find anything that was quiet what I wanted.

Also important I'm new on R and this is a school work! If more information is needed just say.

Thanks in advance

dput() of the data I'm working with

> structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 
>   4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 
>   4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("", 
>   "Pessoal", "Pessoal, Outros", "Pessoal, Profissional", "Pessoal, Profissional, Outros", "Profissional"), class = "factor")

As you can see I have 6 entries on Label and I want to have only 3! But I don't want to delete them I want to count them. For example the entry "Pessoal, Profissional" will count as 1 for "Pessoal" and 1 for "Profissional".

Comment: Please show your input (`dput(your_data)`) and your desired output data.frame. "Remove rows from a data.frame" could be a google search term.

Comment: @Jimbou Edited my answer...see if it represents better what I want! By "desired outpud data.frame" you mean what I want the structure to look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand you correct you want to count each word alone. Therefore, I would use different `stringr` functions to split the words:

```
d <- structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("", "Pessoal", "Pessoal, Outros", "Pessoal, Profissional", "Pessoal, Profissional, Outros", "Profissional"), class = "factor")
library(stringr)
d1 <- str_trim(unlist(str_split(d,",")))
```

and plot the counts

```
barplot(table(d1[d1 != ""]))
```

[image]

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking for! Will read a bit more about stringr. Is there any documentation you recomend about it?

Thanks for the answer!!

Comment: This will be enough: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stringr/vignettes/stringr.html. Alternatively you can use base R `strsplit` and `gsub` to split and remove white spaces.

Comment: Ok I'll take a look at both ways!
Thanks again for the reply